# Converter número para binário

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

Estou tendo problemas na lógica do meu código:

```
dec = (10)
dup = dec
co = 2
exp = 0
res = (tuple)
while True:
    dup = dec
    dec = int(dec / co)
    exp += dup * co
    print(f'dec {dec} dup {dup} exp {exp}')
    if exp - dup == 0:
        res += 0
    elif exp - dup == 1:
        res += 1
    elif dec / co == 0:
        res += 0
        break
print(res)
```

Tentei fazer um tradutor de números decimais para binários de maneira matemática, ele só me retorna `0` e a tupla não acumula os valores.

Comment: Esse código não retorna 0, na verdade ele dá erro: https://ideone.com/jNJuM0 - e está bem confuso, com nomes de variáveis que não ajudam, além de `res = (tuple)` não fazer o menor sentido (a variável recebe a classe `tuple`, e não uma tupla). Sem contar que tuplas são imutáveis e não é o tipo adequado para algo que vai ter coisas adicionadas dinamicamente

Answer (score 1):

O código está bem confuso e realmente não consegui entender como ele tenta converter um número para a base 2. Um fator que contribui para isso são os nomes das variáveis, bem confusos e que não explicam para que serve cada uma. Pode parecer um detalhe sem importância, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda a programar e a entender o que o código faz](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

E como já [dito nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/451221/problemas-com-meu-c%C3%B3digo-python-3/451231#comment863450_451221), esse código não retorna zero, na verdade ele [dá erro ao executar](https://ideone.com/jNJuM0). Um dos motivos é a linha `res = (tuple)`, que não faz sentido. Você está atribuindo a [**classe** `tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) à variável (que é diferente de criar uma tupla contendo alguns valores).

Enfim, uma forma de resolver isso matematicamente (com ressalvas, leia mais sobre isso abaixo) é:

```
# "converte" n para uma outra base
def converter(n, base):
    if base == 10: # se for base 10, retorna o próprio número
        return n

    result = expoente = 0
    while n > 0:
        n, digito = divmod(n, base)
        result += (10 ** expoente) * digito
        expoente += 1

    return result

print(converter(21, 2)) # 10101
```

Usei [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod), que retorna o resultado da divisão e o resto desta divisão (ou seja, a cada iteração `n` é atualizado pelo resultado da divisão por `base`, e o `digito` é o resto desta mesma divisão). Com isso eu já atualizo o valor de `n` e pego o dígito correspondente que será usado.

Depois eu vou somando o dígito ao resultado (eu uso um expoente pois na primeira iteração eu tenho o último dígito, na segunda iteração tenho o penúltimo, etc, então o expoente é para garantir que o dígito ficará na posição correta).

No exemplo acima foi retornado o número `10101`. **Vale lembrar que este é o número "dez mil cento e um". O que eu fiz na verdade foi gerar um número na base 10, cujos dígitos correspondem a 21 na base 2**. Mas o valor dele é dez mil cento e um, então não adianta usá-lo achando que seu valor será `21`.

---

Outro detalhe é que a função só funciona até a base 10, já que bases maiores que isso exigem outros símbolos para representar os dígitos e para isso precisaria gerar uma string em vez de um número. Ou seja, algo assim:

```
def converter(n, base, simbolos):
    if base < 0 or base > len(simbolos):
        raise ValueError('base inválida')
    result = []
    while n > 0:
        result.insert(0, simbolos[n % base])
        n //= base
    return ''.join(result)

simbolos = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
print(converter(27, 2, simbolos)) # 11011
print(converter(27, 16, simbolos)) # 1B
```

Como agora o retorno é uma string, posso usar letras, como no caso de `1B`, que representa 27 na base 16.