# Não consigo printar uma lista(vetor)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer um conversor de decimal para binário segue o código:

```
n = int(input('Insira um número decimal para conversão em binário '))
cont = []
aux = 0
while n > 1:
  if(n % 2 == 0):
    cont.insert(aux,n % 2)
    n = n // 2
  else:
    cont.insert(aux,n % 2)
    n = n // 2
  aux+=1

aux = len(cont)

while aux >= 0:
  print(cont[aux])
  aux-=1
```

já tentei substituir o ultimo while por:

```
for i in range(len(cont), -1, -1):
  print(cont[i])
```

porem não consegui e ainda continua dando o erro IndexError: list index out of range na hora do print do cont, como posso fazer para imprimir o cont?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! O último índice de um vetor é sempre o tamanho do mesmo - 1, porque os índices sempre começam por 0.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado, estava errado também outra parte do código, mas consegui vlw

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451231/112052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente mudar esta linha:

```
aux = len(cont)
```

Para isto:

```
aux = len(cont) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de inserir os dígitos no final da lista e depois invertê-la, por que não inserir os novos elementos sempre no início dela? Assim eles já ficam na ordem certa.

Basta usar sempre o índice zero no `insert`, assim:

```
n = # ler o número

result = []
while n > 0:
    result.insert(0, n % 2) # insere sempre no início da lista
    n //= 2

# depois você imprime os números como achar melhor

# um em cada linha
for i in result:
    print(i)

# ou todos juntos na mesma linha
print(''.join(map(str, result)))
print(*result, sep='')
```

Tendo os números na ordem correta, fica fácil imprimir. Você pode usar o `for` como já estava fazendo, ou se quiser, imprima todos na mesma linha, seja usando [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) ou as opções do próprio [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

Obs: repare como não precisa do `if`/`else`. No seu código você fazia isso:

```
if(n % 2 == 0):
    cont.insert(aux,n % 2)
    n = n // 2
else:
    cont.insert(aux,n % 2)
    n = n // 2
```

Ou seja, fazia exatamente a mesma coisa no `if` e no `else`. Se a mesma coisa é feita independente da condição, então elimine a condição.

---

Outra opção (com ressalvas, veja comentários mais abaixo) é construir o valor usando apenas cálculos. Ex:

```
n = 21
result = expoente = 0
while n > 0:
    n, digito = divmod(n, 2)
    result += (10 ** expoente) * digito
    expoente += 1

print(result) # 10101
```

Usei [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod), que já retorna o resultado da divisão e o resto da mesma (é como usar `//` e `%` de uma vez).

Vale lembrar que nesse caso estou gerando um número na **base 10**, cujos dígitos são os mesmos que `n` na base 2 (no exemplo acima, os dígitos `10101` equivalem a 21 na base 2, mas o valor dele é "dez mil cento e um", então não adianta usar `result` achando que ele vale vinte e um).

---

Por fim, essa transformação é válida como exercício, mas se quiser só mostrar o número na base 2, faça apenas `print(f'{n:b}')`, como já sugeriu [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/471242/112052).

Answer (score 0):

Somente mudar o tamanho do aux ou adicionar - 1 não vai funcionar no caso acima:

Segue uma solução baseada no seu raciocínio:

```
n = int(input('Insira um número decimal para conversão em binário '))
cont = []

while n >= 1:
    cont.append(n % 2)   
    n = n // 2

for item in cont[::-1]:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma interessante para se implementar um conversor de `decimal` para `binário` é:

```
print('=' * 68)
print(f'\033[34m{"Conversor Decimal para Binário":^68}\033[m')
print('=' * 68)

cont = 0
while True:
    cont += 1
    if cont == 1:
        msg = f'um'
    else:
        msg = f'outro'

    n = int(input(f'Insira {msg} número em decimal para converte-lo em binário: '))
    print(f'\033[32mO binário de "{n}" é: {n:b}\033[m')

    resp = input('Desejas converter outro valor? [S/N] ').upper()
    while (len(resp) != 1) or (resp not in 'SN'):
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas "S" ou "N"!\033[m')
        resp = input('Desejas converter outro valor? [S/N] ').upper()
    if resp == 'N':
        break
```

Observe que quando executamos o algoritmo nos é solicitado um número decimal (número na base decimal) e, após inserirmos o valor e pressionarmos `enter`, o algoritmo converte o referido valor para binário e nos pergunta se desejamos realizar outra conversão. Se desejamos converter outro valor, basta pressionar a tecla `s` e, neste momento será novamente solicitado novo valor.

**Observação**

O programa será encerrado após o usuário pressionar a tecla `N`.